# Inverse modulo in algorithm of matrix transpose algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a function

```
y = ((N * x) / (M * N)) + ((N * x) % (M * N))
```

where M and N are constants (it is for matrix transposition). However, I need to solve it for x. I have read multiple topics about Extended Euclidean algorithms or Euler's theorem for inverse modulo, but even if I had finally found the way to implement it, everything suggests that the complexity will be much higher than this. Any suggestions how to proceed, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function simplifies to

```
y = (x / M) + N * (x % M).
```

For `y` such that `0 ≤ y < M * N`, there is a unique solution

```
x = (y / N) + M * (y % N),
```

since this is a transpose after all. The proof is by calculation.

```
  ((x / M) + N * (x % M)) / N + M *  (((x / M)     +  N * (x % M)) % N)
= ((x / M) + N * (x % M)) / N + M * ((((x / M) % N + (N * (x % M)) % N) % N)
= ((x / M) + N * (x % M)) / N + M *  (((x / M) % N)                     % N)
  since (N * ...) % N = 0
= ((x / M) + N * (x % M)) / N + M *    (x / M)
  since 0 ≤ x / M < N
=                 x % M       + M *    (x / M)
  since 0 ≤ x / M < N and N divides N * (x % M)
= x
  by the Euclidean property of / and %.
```

Comment: Many thanks! I wish I could upvote you at least twenty times! I have spent hours on this and now it works flawlessly. Have a nice day :)